# Scala projects stop working on IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

My Scala projects which were working fine recently in IntelliJ, now give me issue when I try to run a program:

Error:Module ‘XXX’ production: sbt.compiler.CompileFailed

What is missing here?

I have posted here too:
https://users.scala-lang.org/t/scala-projects-stop-working-on-intellij/2249

Comment: did you updated scala, sbt, intellij, or any plugin?

Comment: No such change was done explicitly. I did update JDK from 8 to 9 though. But reverting back to 8 also doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Scala is not compatible with jdk9 as far as i know. Probably some sdk configuration got broken on intellij

Comment: Try deleting and importing the module again. You can do that from File -> Project Structure -> In the dialog select Module, then delete and re-import the module again.

I have had situations where IntelliJ goes beserk and confused with Scala projects...re-importing this way usually fixes things for me.

Comment: Reimporting the module worked fro me.Thanks.